# Visual Studios Code insists on starting with a window straddling both monitors -- I don't know what else to try

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, multiple-monitors

thanks for looking. I'm using VS Code 160.0.2 on a Windows 10 notebook. There is an external monitor configured for a much higher resolution. The monitors are in extend mode. With the product installed and reinstalled, and with all of the extensions removed or disabled, I've reached an impasse. The app opens with a window that straddles both the external monitor and the notebook monitor. I can drag the window to my external monitor, but it does not seem to save the change for the next time. There's probably (hopefully?) an easy setting to change -- but I'm not using the right syntax to find it on the Internet.

Your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dear Bot, I open the app, the initial window presents across both my external monitor and half of my laptop monitor. All other apps open one window or the other. I can provide a snapshot of settings but I don't know which settings would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I remember it is caused by an accidental key combination at some point, check this information:

[Visual Studio Code - Tabs (editors)](https://newbedev.com/visual-studio-code-tabs-editors-of-the-same-project-in-multiple-screens)